# Text file into Java Set<String> using Commons or Guava

Tags: java, text-files, guava, hashset

I would like to load each line in a file into HashSet collection. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about:

```
Sets.newHashSet(Files.readLines(file, charSet));
```

(using Guava).

References:

- [Files.readLines()](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#readLines%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)
- [Sets.newHashSet()](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#newHashSet(java.lang.Iterable))

Comment: With static imports this becomes `newHashSet(readLines(file, charSet));`

Answer (score 11):

You can do

```
Set<String> lines = new HashSet<String>(FileUtils.readLines(new File("foo.txt")));
```

Using the Apache Commons [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) class and the [readlines](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.File%29) method.

Comment: `readLines` method is deprecated, use `readLines(File, Charset)` instead

Answer (score 2):

**Multiset** can store duplicated strings, if your text contains duplicated lines. (add ordering)

```
Multiset<String> set = LinkedHashMultiset.create();
```

Answer (score 0):

With [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) you have [`readLines`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.File%29) which returns a `List`. You can then add all elements from the returned list into your `HashSet` (beware: type compatibility between `List` and `Set`, and loosing duplicated lines).