# How do I get a Java resource as a File?

Tags: java, file, jar, resources

I have to read a file containing a list of strings. I'm trying to follow the advice in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804269/text-file-into-java-setstring-using-commons-or-guava).  Both solutions require using `FileUtils.readLines`, but use a `String`, not a `File` as the parameter.

```
Set<String> lines = new HashSet<String>(FileUtils.readLines("foo.txt"));
```

I need a `File`.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676097/java-resource-as-file) *would* be my question, except the OP was dissuaded from using files entirely. I need a file if I want to use the Apache method, which is the my preferred solution to my initial problem.

My file is small (a hundred lines or so) and a singleton per program instance, so I do not need to worry about having another copy of the file in memory. Therefore I could use more basic methods to read the file, but so far it looks like `FileUtils.readLines` could be much cleaner. How do I go from resource to file.

Comment: If it is a classpath resource you should not be using the `File` type. Consider using Google's [Guava library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) `Resources.readLines` method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apache Commons-IO has an [IOUtils class](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) as well as a FileUtils, which includes a [`readLines` method](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.InputStream%29) similar to the one in FileUtils.

So you can use [`getResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) or [`getSystemResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) and pass the result of that to `IOUtils.readLines` to get a `List<String>` of the contents of your file:

```
List<String> myLines = IOUtils.readLines(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("my_data_file.txt"));
```

Comment: lol, so another question accepting an answer that bypasses the getting File problem. Java really doesn't like File apparently.

Comment: Has nothing to do with it. File is not system agnostic, Stream is.

Comment: @djechlin a `File` is an actual file in the filesystem that has a path. Resources can be part of a jar file and you can't refer to just a part of a jar (or zip) through a path. What you can do is to get a stream to either a real file or a stream to a compressed file in an archive that also unzips on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming the file you want to read is a true resource on your classpath, and not simply some arbitrary file you could just access via `new File("path_to_file");`.

Try the following using `ClassLoader`, where `resource` is a `String` representation of the path to your resource file in your class path.

Valid `String` values for `resource` can include:

- `"foo.txt"`
- `"com/company/bar.txt"`
- `"com\\company\\bar.txt"`
- `"\\com\\company\\bar.txt"`

and path is not limited to `com.company`

Relevant code to get a `File` not in a JAR:

```
File file = null;

try {

    URL url = null;
    ClassLoader classLoader = {YourClass}.class.getClassLoader(); 

    if (classLoader != null) {

        url = classLoader.getResource(resource);
    }

    if (url == null) {

        url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(resource);
    }

    if (url != null) {

        try {

            file = new File(url.toURI());

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {

            file = new File(url.getPath());
        }
    }

} catch (Exception ex) { /* handle it */ }

// file may be null
```

Alternately, if your resource is in a JAR, you will have to use              `Class.getResourceAsStream(resource);` and cycle through the file using a `BufferedReader` to simulate the call to `readLines()`.

Comment: Should resource be the string, e.g. "`/com/mysite/app/file.txt"`?

Comment: No, not with the preceding `/`.  I've tested it on Windows 7 and updated with my successful test cases.  Does not work with `.` as a path separator.

Comment: After reviewing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676097/java-resource-as-file , one of the alternate answers there is similar, but not as wide in scope, as my answer.

Comment: Will `new File(url.toURI())` work for resources in JAR files?

Comment: That was exactly what I was JUST going to update with; might have to use `getResourceAsStream()` and a `BufferedReader` in place of a call to `FileUtils`.

Answer (score 0):

using a resource to read the file to a string:

```
String contents = 
 FileUtils.readFileToString(
  new File(this.getClass().getResource("/myfile.log").toURI()));
```

using inputstream:

```
List<String> listContents = 
 IOUtils.readLines(
  this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myfile.log"));
```